# What could cause a "command failed" error when using the Word.Application object to compare two documents?

Tags: automated-testing, testcomplete8

I have two word documents that are a "result" of a test and an "expected result".  I'm using the following code to compare the two and check for differences.

```
Sub CompareTest 
  Dim wrdApp 
  Dim revTemp 
  Dim file1, file2, differences 
  Set wrdApp = Sys.OleObject("Word.Application") 
  file1 = "C:\TestDocs\Site Initiation.doc"   
  file2 = "C:\TestDocs\Site Initiation_observer.doc" 
  differences = "C:\TestDocs\differences.doc" 
  call wrdApp.Documents.Open(file1)  
  call wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Compare(file2, "", 1)   
  Set revTemp = wrdApp.Selection.NextRevision(True) 
  If Not (revTemp Is Nothing) Then 
    wrdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs differences  
    wrdApp.Documents.Close 
    Call Log.Warning "Documents are not identical", "Please see the differences in " & differences  
  Else 
    Call Log.Message "Documents are identical"    
  End If 
  wrdApp.Quit False 
End Sub
```

For whatever reason, for most of the word documents we're comparing like this, everything works fine.  However, for two of them we're comparing, we're getting "Command Failed" on the line that is calling the "Compare" method.

I've searched Microsoft's library on line, numerous blogs, etc., and no one can give me a specific situation where this code would work for MOST documents but not for certain scenarios.  I've tried reversing the order of the documents, changing the document names and the directory paths to be more compatible with an 8.3 format.  I've tried comparing each document to itself as well.

A little help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI, this is code being run in the TestComplete automated testing tool so the specifics of "Sys.OleObject" and the "Log" object are internal to that tool.  We've used "CreateObject" and commented out the Log calls to no avail.

Comment: Do you know which line is causing the command failed message? I assume it's the Compare command, but I wanted to make sure. Then, is there anything interesting with the content with the docs that fail (embedded objects, etc.)? Finally, what happens if you try to compare the docs outside the script - i.e. using the Compare feature on the Review ribbon?

Comment: The Compare line is what fails.  The docs have form fields in them but the other docs we've compared also have form fields and we've not run into any problem.  As for using the Compare feature, that's working just fine with either a Merge, Merge to New, Merge to same, or straight compare.  That's why this is such a mystery, everything LOOKS like it should work... but it's not.  And I have asked for help from the tool vendor and they have not been able to find anything (since, technically, it's not their tool causing the error).

Comment: So you don't have to open the second document to compare the two? It opens the document for you when you call Compare()? You could try writing a VB.Net or C# console app and see if some exception details are returned...

Comment: A little additional info... the Word documents are Word 2007 formatted docs.  We've used the Word.Application object on both a machine with Word 2010 and Word 2003 installed without any change in behavior

Comment: @BrMcMullin - The compare routine is called from an existing document to compare to a different document.  Much like if, in Word, you have a document open and go to "Compare and Merge" and operate a compare there.  Both documents don't have to be open to do the comparison.

Comment: I pinged a colleague on the Word team for ideas. In the meantime, have you tried renaming the files - I just wanted to rule out that the filename or location wasn't the problem.

Comment: Location I know is not the problem.  The locations in the code above are not the same locations as on the machine with Word 2010 so directory name isn't the problem or drive location.  Also, I've replaced the spaces in the filenames with underscores and that hasn't had any effect.  I can try shortening both but, again, other docs with equally long names (or longer) are working fine.  For whatever reason, these two docs are giving me grief and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Other random ideas to try (only if you want) would be to change the order (open doc2 first then compare with doc1), or compare doc1 with doc1, then doc2 with doc2 (or edited variations) to see if it's one of the docs that is causing the problem. Still waiting to hear from my Word contact.

Comment: While it is never their fault, I wouldn't rule out the vendor's Compare function. It probably goes without saying here, but it seems there is something in the malfunctioning docs that is different from similar docs that are working. (e.g. formmating, char sequences, encoding, etc.) and you might need a hex editor or similar tool to look for differences and see if that helps to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Alan I have tried comparing doc 1 to doc 1 and doc 2 to doc 2 with the same result.  I've also tried reversing the doc order, also with no effect.  Obviously, a serious mystery here.

Comment: @Bj - the compare function is part of the word object model - the vendor is MS :}

Comment: @Alan, I believe my comment still stands :-)

Comment: If it's possible to sanitize the docs enough to share, I'm happy to poke around a bit with them myself (still no reply from my Word contact).

Comment: @Alan I'll take a look and see what needs "cleaned up".  Should be pretty straight forward.  How do I contact you to send the docs?

Comment: you can email them to alanpa at where I work dot com :}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My transcribed debugging session is below - the short answer is that Compare will fail if there are unaccepted revision changes in the comparison document.

**Details**:

Here are some clues and potential answers.

1. I reproduced the error
2. I made a copy of the first doc and compared it with itself – that worked.
3. I made a copy of the second file and compared it with itself – that reproduced the command failed error
4. I tried comparing the docs from step3 (…observation.doc) manually from word. It worked, but I had to confirm that it was ok to compare against tracked changes
5. Based on the above, I accepted all changes and saved the original doc, then reran the comparison – it worked!

So – it has something to do with the unaccepted changes to the doc.

My final experiment was to take a simple doc, turn on track changes, make some edits, then save without accepting. I compared this doc with itself and reproduced the error (command failed).

My advice: save the unaccepted changes before comparing (you can probably use Document.AcceptAllRevisions from the script if you want to).

Comment: +1 Bravo, @Alan!  As I suspected, it was something that was simply an unexpected condition on the documents.  The thing is, the revisions that are in the two docs are not visible, necessarily, and so opening up the documents did not expose them.

Comment: +1 to Alan here, too. I've been having the same issue with very similar comparison code - now I know how to deal with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Created an automated appliction (.exe) to generate word document by using windows schedular we are calling the .exe file for every 1 hour.

while saving (saveas) throwing an error message "Command failed", if it is executed by using windows scheduler(selected even user logged off the system option).

Not throwing an error (creating the document successfully) by manually executing the .exe file.

Comment: Sree, this looks like you have a new question - you're more likely to have someone answer your question if you post it as a question.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Sree. I have to admit, I'm having trouble tying your answer to the question that was asked. If it is supposed to be an answer, you'll want to shore it up by bringing it into context. If it is indeed a new question, you should hit the "ask question" link at the top of this page, or right here:  http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/ask